# Yii2. Выполнить код перед созданием контроллера

Tags: yii2, dependency-injection

В Yii2 есть возможность определять в параметрах конструктора интерфейсы, и туда будут попадать нужные реализации, определенные через Yii::$container->set();

Например в контроллере авторизации я делаю так

```
public function __construct($id, $module, IAuthModelBuilder $modelBuilder, IAuthorizator $auth){}
```

Реализации все определены в отдельном файлике и подгружаются прямо в конфиг.

Теперь мне необходимо в зависимости от того, что передано в запросе изменить реализацию `IAuthorizator`

В конфиге можно задать событие 'on beforeRequest', но там еще не ясно какой контроллер и действие.

beforeAction тоже не подходит, т.к. в этом месте контроллер уже создан и ему переданы реализации.

Как быть? Где есть место, где контроллер еще не создан, но url уже распознан?

Comment: Создайте класс, который может вернуть обе реализации и инжектьте его.

Comment: @vp_arth Получается двойной инжект) хотелось бы одним уровнем обойтись)

Comment: Тут лучше всего подойдет передавать фабрику а не конкретный обьект.

Answer (score 0):

Почему вы не хотите разрешить зависимость через отдельный метод?

```
// remove dependency from here
public function __construct($id, $module, IAuthModelBuilder $modelBuilder){}

public function actionAuthorize() {
   $auth = $this->getAuthorizator();
   // another part of code;
}

private function getAuthorizator() : IAuthorizator {
   if (Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQuery()) {
      // return needed auth module here
   }
}
```

Почитайте про различные способы внедрения зависимости [тут](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/concept-di-container/). Внедрение не ограничивается только конструктором.

Comment: Я думал в этом фишка DI, что контроллер менять не приходится, а поведение меняется.

Comment: Кроме resolver-а в виде функции getAuthorizator() вам ничего и не придётся менять. Можно, конечно, попытаться его вынести на уровень повыше, но надо ли оно? Посмотрите на callable-реализацию, возможно она как раз то, что вам нужно http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html#php-callable-injection Тогда вы точно избавитесь от реализации логики в контроллере и будете запрашивать $container->get('auth')

Comment: Я пока что сделал в beforeRequest обработчик зависимостей, тоже вне контроллера, но беда в том, что там не разобран url еще. Посмотрел по ссылке, возможно внедрить зависимость прямо в экшн, и вызывать обработчик в глобальном beforeAction - там уже ясен и контроллер и все остальное. Спасибо за помощь!